# My splash screen changed from kubuntu to lubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, bootsplash

So my splash screen changed from kubuntu breeze to lubuntu splash screen. How can I fix this?
This happened ever since I installed `lxde`, but not `lubuntu-desktop`. How did this happen?

Answer (score 0):

When you install a new distribution, it installs grub on your hard drive, using the distribution default configuration for grub.

To restore the kubuntu splash screen, you need to replace the current grub by that of Kubuntu. To do so, just run, from Kubuntu:

```
sudo update-grub
```